# solr searching with wildcard in the end

Tags: solr, wildcard

I have a piece of data in my database with id=*CREDIT.BOND.US12658TAA51.SPRED_TSY*

When I search with query: `xxxxxx/select?q=CREDIT.BOND.US12658TAA51.SPRED_TSY*`, I couldn't get any result back. But when I add quote around, which becomes: `xxxxxx/select?q="CREDIT.BOND.US12658TAA51.SPRED_TSY*"`, then i get the piece of data back.

So what is wrong with my first query?

Comment: Are you sure you're querying the `id` field? When you don't have a field name in `q`, the default search field is used (usually `_text_` by default). The `id` field will usually be defined as a `string` field, and `q=id:CREDIT.BOND.US12658TAA51.SPRED_TSY*` should give you any prefix matches in the id field.